# Isomorphisms between elements in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $n \times 1$ column matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

In the book *Analysis on Manifolds by Munkres* there is the following passage

[image]

Now in my exposure to Linear Algebra, I always thought that elements in $\mathbb{R}^n$ could be "represented" (informally) as $1 \times n$ row vectors (or row matrices in Munkres' terminology) or as $n \times 1$ column vectors (or column matrices in Munkres' terminology).

However Munkres states that there exists a linear isomorphism (vector space isomorphism) between elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and their corresponding row/column matrices.  But while $\mathbb{R}^n$ is certainly a vector space, what is the other vector space(s) that Munkres is asserting that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is isomorphic to (as vector spaces)?

I'm guessing that it's the set of all $n \times 1$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$ and similarly the  $1 \times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes, it's  exactly that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$, the set of all $m\times n$ matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$ is a [vector space](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/the-vector-space-of-m-x-n-matrices) (over $\mathbb{R}$). Mukners claims that 
$$ \mathbb{R}^n \cong M_{1\times n}(\mathbb{R}) \cong M_{n\times 1}(\mathbb{R}) $$

Answer (score 2):

As you know every n-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb {R}$  is isomorphic to   $\mathbb {R^n}$

Thus

$$ \mathbb{R}^n \cong M_{1\times n}(\mathbb{R}) \cong M_{n\times 1}(\mathbb{R})$$ is  a special case  of above statement.

Another example is the set of $n\times n$  real diagonal matrices.